# Protecting static downloads in Apache2 with S3-like REST authentication?

Tags: apache2, amazon-s3, restful-authentication

I'd like to expose static download content served by a regular apache2 process with REST authenticated links similar to those offered by Amazon S3, as in http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html .

I.e., I want to be able to serve download with authenticated, expiring links of the form:
http://www.example.com/download/download.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=44CF9590006BF252F707&Expires=1141889120&Signature=vjbyPxybdZaNmGa%2ByT272YEAiv4%3D

from my own server. And I'd like it to be compatible to S3 so I can scale out from my dedicated server to the cloud should the need arise.

It seems the best way to this would be an apache authz_module that checks the appropriate query parameters. For efficiency, I would prefer not to carry mod_(perl|python|php), and not send the actual content via the script.

This seems like a requirement that might come up fairly regularly. Nevertheless, I couldn't find anything relevant on the net. I was wondering if and how other people have solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it: I used a

- a **custom CGI script** in ruby that implements the subset of S3 REST authentication I need
- and **[mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)** for sending the download to the client.

All the CGI script has to do is send the X-Sendfile header when authentication succeeds, then apache2 takes over and transmits the file with full speed / Cache tags support etc.

Works well for me, as the number of download requests per second is small. And the the solution does not bloat the apache2 process with any expensive|error_prone scripting modules.